# How do I grep a list in multiple columns?

Tags: bash, grep

in `bash` I use `grep -w -f list1.txt list2.txt` to search a list1 name into list2, they are one-column files. 
Now I need to search this list1's namesinto a multiple columns file (a matrix, tab delimited or csv), how do I get the name and the corresponding column number?

List1 is:

```
SERPINA3  
ADRA1D  
BDNF  
ADSS
```

Matrix is:

```
**CLUST1  CLUST2  CLUST3**  
AAMP    A1BG    ACACB  
ACADSB  A2M ADRA1D  
ACO1    SERPINA3    AK4  
ACP5    ACADM   ALDH1A3  
PLIN2   ACR AMD1  
ADORA2B ACO2    ARSB  
ADSL    ALAS1   BDNF  
ADSS    ALB OSGIN2
```

output should be

```
SERPINA3 CLUST2  
ADRA1D CLUST2  
BDNF CLUST3  
ADSS CLUST1
```

Thanks.

Comment: `awk` is another command-line tool that may be more suitable than `grep` in this case.

Comment: yes, sorry @fedorqui, I posted the example

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} 
        FNR==1{split($0,h);next} 
              {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) print $i, h[i]}' file{1,2}

ADRA1D CLUST3
SERPINA3 CLUST2
BDNF CLUST3
ADSS CLUST1
```

you lose the order of file1, there are other ways to handle it, not sure it's important.

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR{a[$0];next}`  store records of first file in array **a**, skip the rest while processing first file

`FNR==1{split($0,h);next}` now we know it's the second file, split the header to  array **h** for reference of column names (first row), skip rest

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` main loop for the second file for each record (line) iterate over all fields

`if($i in a)`  if any field is in the array **a** (that is first file)

`print $i, h[i]}`  print the field and column name (indexed by the field number)

`file{1,2}` shorthand for file1 file2, your case will be List1 Matrix

Comment: I'd kill the indents there; the three AWK clauses should (imho) be aligned with each other since they're at the same hierarchical level (though you do have those `next` statements; maybe you were just highlighting that?)

Comment: I align the actions for each condition{action} block.  It's like aligning multiple line equations at the equal sign.

Comment: thanks @karakfa, order of `file1` is not important, but in order to let me learn `awk` use, could you please specify what each line does (and where are input filenames `file1` & `matrix`)?

Comment: Ok I got at least that `file{1,2}`are my files.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush, added explanation now.